# How can I find lost followers?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I was doing the quests **Recovering Cloudcleaver** and **Pemenie and the Boots of Blinding Speed**, and both the nord guy and Pemenie were following me. I was attacked by a monster and I ran away, leaving my followers behind and now I can't find them, and their quests are still active on my journal.

How can I find them in order to complete the quests?

Comment: Do you have access to the cheat console? Short of that, you'll have to form a search & rescue party. I recommend calling Civil Air Patrol for backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using a console:

If you are playing on PC, you can move yourself to NPC by his refID.

### Example:

> Player.Moveto XX

Where XX is his refID.
I highly recommend you not to move NPC to Player, command will simply create NPC's double.

Comment: This worked like a charm!